# PHP preg_match year validation 1900 to 2019

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to validate a date in dd-mm-yyyy format, where the year should be between 1900 to 2019.

The day and month part work fine, but i'm failing with the year part. Can you pls help?

```
$date="31-12-2020";

if (preg_match("/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(19[0-9]{2}|20([0-1]|[0-9]){2})$/",$date)) {
        echo 'True';
    return true;
} else {
        echo 'False';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is a bad way to validate date, what if for example you have 30-02-2019, it will still be true; Use string to time function, convert date format and than you can   properly validate date range

Comment: Why should you do it with regex?

Answer (score 5):

This is complete script that you need; function will return true or false if given date is in range:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c0e8108319a24ae5ecf993bb940e1f30aab53fc7

```
$start_date = '01-01-1900';
$end_date = '01-01-2019';
$date_from_user = '01-01-2018';

check_in_range($start_date, $end_date, $date_from_user);


function check_in_range($start_date, $end_date, $date_from_user,$format='d-m-Y')
{
  // Convert to timestamp
  $start_ts = DateTime::createFromFormat($format,$start_date);
  $end_ts = DateTime::createFromFormat($format,$end_date);
  $user_ts = DateTime::createFromFormat($format,$date_from_user);

  // Check that user date is between start & end
  return (($user_ts >= $start_ts) && ($user_ts <= $end_ts));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current year part `20([0-1]|[0-9]){2}` for handling years 2000 to 2019 just needs little modification to make it correct. Third digit in year part can only be `0` or `1` hence it can be written as `[01]` and fourth digit can be any hence can be written as `[0-9]` and that gives us `20[01][0-9]`. Following is your modified regex you can use,

```
^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(19[0-9]{2}|20[01][0-9])$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XB4sPq/1/)**

Also, since you're just validating your text, you can convert all groups as non-capturing groups to make it little better performance wise.

```
^(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:19[0-9]{2}|20[01][0-9])$
```

**[Demo with non-capturing group](https://regex101.com/r/XB4sPq/2)**

Answer (score -1):

This think year expression should as below

```
19[0-9][0-9] | 20[0-1][0-9]
```